# partitions of sets

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, tree, nodes

in the last level of the tree I have to generate all possible subsets that make up the original set. but those subsets shouldnt have any common elements[image]
here the original set is {a,b,c}

figure description:

with **in** I meant next member will be in the subset 
with **out** next member will be out of subset
Thanks in Advance

I wrote this recursive code Due to this [data stucture](http://vivin.net/2010/01/30/generic-n-ary-tree-in-java/)
which will give tree with many children

```
public class Mymethod {
    public GenericTreeNode<String> insert(GenericTreeNode<String> root,GenericTreeNode<String> NewNode)
    {
    int index=root.getNumberOfChildren()-1;
    if(root.hasChildren())
    while(index!=-1)
    {
    insert(root.getChildAt(index),NewNode);
    index--;
    }
    root.children.add(NewNode);
    ArrayList ChList = new ArrayList();
    ChList.add("{"+root.getData()+","+NewNode+"}");
    ChList.add("{"+root.getData()+"}"+"{"+NewNode+"}");
    root.children=ChList;
    return root;
    }
    }
```

I wrote Simple Main for my debug my debug will answer until level2 of tree

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    GenericTreeNode<String> root=new GenericTreeNode<String>("a");
    GenericTreeNode<String> str=new GenericTreeNode<String>("b");
    GenericTreeNode<String> str1=new GenericTreeNode<String>("c");
    Mymethod m=new Mymethod();
    GenericTreeNode<String> parent=m.insert(root, str);
    GenericTreeNode<String> parent1=m.insert(parent, str1);
        }
```

The problem is that in `root.getChildAt(index)` it will give an exception I know why but i don't know how to solve the problem is that I should have Nodes but the ChList here is type of the String
Due to the link I should call addchildAt but I don't know how?
any Idea would be so so and so appreciated!

I really need Help! really really.

Comment: you need to attempt this yourself

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but aren't `{a}{b}` and `{a,b}` equivalent? If so I have a working solution, if not I'm half way to a working solution.

Comment: would you please tell me yours? maybe i can change it I wrote permutations and I also have numbers which will be partitioned like 5 and 2,3 and 1,1,2,1 and etc I mixed them I have partitions but I want this approach not just the whole I am really confused it is hard

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I tried two days working 14 hours on this but maybe it is so hard or maybe i am stupid that i can't do it